# How to set a SELECT control using text instead of value using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<SELECT id='cars'>
   <OPTION value='1'>Car One</option>
   <OPTION value='2'>Second Car</option>
   <OPTION value='3'>Another Car</option>
</SELECT>
```

And I know that I can change the selected value of the drop-down control to any value using:

```
$('#cars').val(2);   // This will make the combo text: Second Car
```

But how can I select a value using the text rather than the value?

What I need to do is something like:

```
$('#cars').val('Another Car');
```

or

```
$('#cars').text('Another Car');
```

but that has no effect...

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the value that contains the text, then you may use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('#cars option:contains("Another Car")');
```

<strike>As per @Burimi suggestion: contains will try to match it's value as well, so you have to use text attribute</strike>

`$('#cars').find('option[text*="Another Car"]').val();`

Sorry, for confusion made by comment. But contains just match it's text not it's value.

Comment: I don't want to change the text of the option.. I just need to select the value by TEXT not by INDEX

Comment: contains will try to match it's value as well, so you have to use text attribute, $('#cars').find('option[text*="Another Car"]').val();

Comment: The first method worked fine. The second one did not. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var text="text";
var check=$('#cars').find('option[text='+text'+]').val();
        $('#cars').val(check);
```

Comment: this would not work, because the values contain spaces and that would cause errors selecting the right option